# Template Builder has stopped working

Tags: 2013-sp1, template-builder

I installed Template Builder in window 7, after installation I got this error and not open Template Builder.

[image]

Looking for suggestion and solution for this issue.

Comment: This is rather generic and too broad question. Have you checked logs on cm side? Also, are you running it as admin user? DO you have any errors in your event viewer on your machine?

Comment: Maybe "Debug the program" provides a bit more insight in how it crashes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If this happens as soon as it starts, it suggests that there is a problem with the ClickOnce application. I've seen this most often when people have used Firefox or Chrome to install Template Builder.

As highlighted [in the documentation](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-9106E653-71D2-4E33-83B6-A30F544F49FB), you should use Internet Explorer to install the application the first time. After that, you *may* be able to launch it from a different browser (might need some extensions) -- and you certainly will be able to run it from the Start menu like any other application.